# If I publish a binary will all components that reference that binary also be published?

Tags: 2013

If I publish a binary will all components that reference that binary also be published?  If yes, is this always the case?  How do I control this behavior?  For example, how can I make sure all referencing components are published or make sure that the binary only is published?

We're using Tridion 2013.

Comment: Custom resolvers give most granular control over what gets published. See http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/custom-resolver

Comment: Also, Tridion has this great button on the bottom left of the Publish Dialog that shows what _would_ be published.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you publish a Multimedia Component containing a binary (Image, word document, etc.), then, by default, all of the Components that include your Multimedia Component will also be included for publish.

As Frank says in his comment, you could do this using a Custom Resolver (and having a Dynamic Component Template associated with the Schema of your Multimedia Component). Using a Custom Resolver allows you to modify the logic that Publisher uses for determining what should be published. It is a supported extension point for Tridion. More details on Customer Resolvers can be found in the [Custom resolving](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-F792AB1A-060A-4757-802D-3A2DB18F022D) section of the online documentation (login required).

Alternatively, and something that is sometimes done for CSS images, is to have Page Templating code that adds the necessary binaries to the package (when a specific Page is published). This would prevent you having to re-publish the binary Component itself. However, **I would advise against this approach if the binaries that you are publishing are genuine 'content'** (and not system items related to the page).